# 1x GTX 1080 or 2x GTX 970

Tags: graphics-cards, pc

I want to build a new PC for myself and have a question about my graphics-card.

I don't know which to buy:
1x Asus ROG Nvidia GTX 1080
2x MSI Nvidia GTX 970 (+1x SLI-Bridge)

What would be most effective and also the best for the future, because I want to use this computer for a longer time (because I dont want to spend so much money every 2 years)

Please explain your statement (why you think XY is better then AB)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While purchasing two cards may **seem gnarly**, it really **wouldn't be better** than a **single 1080**.

First, you won't have to fuss around with getting **SLI** to work properly. Not that its a massive pain, but it is a pain.

Second, some games **do not even support SLI properly**. Now this may **not happen often**, but imagine your shock when your $1000+ GPU setup won't play nice with certain games. (Don't get me wrong, I know *most* games support SLI, but this doesn't change the fact that there **are some compatibility issues** with certain games...)

Third, **power consumption**. It may not be a huge issue, but its another issue to stack on-top of the other issues that come with running two cards. (~150 watts per 970, vs ~250 for a single 1080)

Fourth, **resale value**. Not that you'll want to sell, but this is still something to think about.

Fifth, as far as numbers go, you're looking at about **20 percent more performance** out of the 1080 for less work and you **don't have to worry** about all of **issues** that I've mentioned.

...Now say... you want to run two ***980 TI's in SLI***... I'd have to reconsider my answer entirely at that point!

But if you want one takeaway:

***Two 970's running in SLI are not better than one 1080.***

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation :) - I will buy the GTX 1080 as I planned from the beginning ^^ I just started thinking about it, because 2 970s cost a little bit less. But with that in mind I will go for the 1080. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted and want to upvote a million times over. Wonderfully written, totally accurate, and epic formatting. 10/10 =)